# Reshape dataframe in R with library reshape2 or similar

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, reshape2

I have dataframe like this:

```
Id  Date
1   12.3.2011
1   22.2.2012
1   15.8.2015
2   2.7.2017
2   2.10.2017
3   1.9.2014
3   31.1.2015
3   11.11.2016
```

How to get dataframes in R like this:

```
Id  Date_1      Date_2      Date_3
1   12.3.2011   22.2.2012   15.8.2015
2   2.7.2017    2.10.2017   
3   1.9.2014    31.1.2015   11.11.2016
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is usually called 'long-to-wide' reshape. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution based on `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(Number = paste0("Date", 1:n())) %>%
  spread(Number, Date)
dt2
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Id [3]
     Id     Date1     Date2      Date3
* <int>     <chr>     <chr>      <chr>
1     1 12.3.2011 22.2.2012  15.8.2015
2     2  2.7.2017 2.10.2017       <NA>
3     3  1.9.2014 31.1.2015 11.11.2016
```

Or with the `dcast` function from the `reshape2` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(Number = paste0("Date", 1:n())) %>%
  dcast(Id ~ Number, value.var = "Date")
dt2
  Id     Date1     Date2      Date3
1  1 12.3.2011 22.2.2012  15.8.2015
2  2  2.7.2017 2.10.2017       <NA>
3  3  1.9.2014 31.1.2015 11.11.2016
```

Or use the `data.table` package.

```
dt_temp <- as.data.table(dt)
dt_temp2 <- dt_temp[, Number := paste0("Date", as.character(1:.N)), by = Id]

dcast(dt_temp2, Id ~ Number, value.var = "Date")
   Id     Date1     Date2      Date3
1:  1 12.3.2011 22.2.2012  15.8.2015
2:  2  2.7.2017 2.10.2017         NA
3:  3  1.9.2014 31.1.2015 11.11.2016
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "Id  Date
1   12.3.2011
1   22.2.2012
1   15.8.2015
2   2.7.2017
2   2.10.2017
3   1.9.2014
3   31.1.2015
3   11.11.2016",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```